# click on element inside of iFrame

Tags: c#, html, browser, webbrowser-control

My built-in browser downloaded a page.
On this page under "body", there is an "iframe" tag.
Inside of this iframe, there is another code (div tags, table etc).
But I don't know how to access them.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myiFrame").innerHTML // gives out empty result as if there is nothing there.
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myiFrame").FirstChild.innerHTML // gives an error as if there is no first child.
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mylink") // error as if it doesn't exist
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")[2] // error as if it doesn't eist
```

I ran out of options.

I need to click a thing that is deep inside of this frame:

```
body -> div -> div -> div -> form -> div -> div -> div -> div -> div -> div -> div -> div -> table -> tbody -> tr -> td -> a
```

Comment: When you say "GetElementsByTagName" doesn't work - you mean that document.GetElementsByTagName didn't work? Because if you do the entire document it should find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does 
   `Document.InvokeScript([whatever it is you want to click]`

Work?

Are you sure that its all downloaded? Webbrowser.ReadyState triggers Ready for every frame.

Comment: I'm sure the element is downloaded because 1) I see it on the screen; 2) Firebug in Firefox does see it (in fact, this is the only way to see the html, e.g. View Source doesn't see it).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the parent page and going through it, you should load the page which appears within iframe. You can get src attribute of iframe and navigate to the page. This way you can easily access nodes you need to access.